# Exporting to CSV based on date and attaching that file to an email

Tags: powershell-3.0, exchange-server-2010

With the following script, it was my intention to achieve the following goals:

1. Create a CSV file from a series of Exchange commands with the file being named based on the date and time.
2. Attach that same file to an email.

The current iteration of my script is as follows:

```
$ems = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri `
       http://exchangehubcas.mydomain.com/powershell

Import-PSSession $ems -DisableNameChecking

function getRepQ {
    Get-MailboxDatabase | Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus |
        Sort-Object mailboxserver |
        Select-Object -Property mailboxserver, name, status, copyqueuelength,
            replayqueuelength, contentindexstate |
        Export-Csv -Path "c:\admin\scripts\exchange\ExchangeReplication_$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm-ss')).csv"
}

function qchk {
    $nowfile = getRepQ 
    $data = Get-Content -Path $nowfile | Select-Object -Skip 1 |
            Out-String | ConvertFrom-Csv |
            Select-Object -Property status -Unique
    $repStat = $data.Status
    foreach ($_ in $repStat) {
        if ($_ -eq "Healthy") {
            Send-MailMessage -Attachments $nowfile -From admin@mydomain.com `
                -To jsmith@mydomain.com -Subject "Database replication failed" ` 
                -Body "Review attached CSV file for more details." `
                -SmtpServer exchangehubcas.mydomain.com
        }
    }
}

qchk
```

Ultimately "Healthy" will be changed to "Failed", but while the .CSV file is correctly generated, it fails on the `qchk` function saying that the path for `Get-Content` is null.

What am I doing wrong and what is the correct way to accomplish my desired goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `getRepQ` exports the data from `Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus` to a CSV, but doesn't return anything. Hence nothing is assigned to the variable `$nowfile` when you call the function in `qchk`.

Change this:

```psh
function getRepQ {
    Get-MailboxDatabase | Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus |
        Sort-Object mailboxserver |
        Select-Object -Property mailboxserver, name, status, copyqueuelength,
            replayqueuelength, contentindexstate |
        Export-Csv -Path "c:\admin\scripts\exchange\ExchangeReplication_$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm-ss')).csv"
}
```

to this:

```psh
function getRepQ {
    $date = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm-ss')
    $csv  = "C:\admin\scripts\exchange\ExchangeReplication_$date.csv"

    Get-MailboxDatabase | Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus |
        Sort-Object mailboxserver |
        Select-Object -Property mailboxserver, name, status, copyqueuelength,
            replayqueuelength, contentindexstate |
        Export-Csv -Path $csv

    $csv
}
```

and the function will both export the data to a CSV *and* and return the path of that CSV to the caller.

Comment: Thanks!  For some reason it is still failing on the get-content line with path is null.  The qchk function starts off by calling getRepQ.  I've tried adding an additional variable line $nowfile = $csv, but either way it doesn't seem to work in the get-content command.  The csv is indeed getting created correctly.

Comment: Umm... does it work, or does it not work? If it doesn't work: please add the modified code and any new error message to your question.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  Yes, it does work as per your suggestions.  Thank you again for your help.